# jQuery sometimes not changing video src

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, wordpress

In a wordpress page. I have a  tag that autoplays whenever the page is loaded. Everytime i resize the window the video restarts playing.I have a function that everytime if the url contains (/home/en) it changes the video (src) attribute, but for some reason, sometimes it doesn't.

```
jQuery(window).resize(function() {
        if(window.location.href.includes("/home/en")){
            jQuery('#testID').attr('src','https://test.mp4');
        }
    });
```

Does anyone have any idea what might be the problem!

Comment: A side question, since I am not too familiar with jquery: wont that set the attribute dozens of times while resizing?

Comment: Yes it does.But thats not the reason the video restart because i tried this without this function

Comment: What code are you using to play the video whenever the page is loaded? The lines you posted seem fine.

Comment: <video id="testID" class="vid" autoplay muted width="100%" height="auto" playsinline preload="auto">
<source src="https://test.mp4"  type="video/mp4">
</video>
Im using this, but puting a short timeout seemed to fix the problem.Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can not tell you why it sometimes fails, except that your `location` does not include what you want it to. Yet you only have to check it once.

```js
//only need to check this once per window    
var PlayVideo = window.location.href.includes("/home/en");
var PlayTimeout = null;

jQuery(window).resize(function(){
    //adding a timeout to prevent multiple calls
    window.clearTimeout(PlayTimeout);
    PlayTimeout = window.setTimeout(function(){
        if(PlayVideo){
            jQuery('#testID').attr('src','https://test.mp4');
        }
        else{
            //if you reach this point, your condition is not what you want it to be
            console.log(window.location.href)
        }
    }, 1000)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This works in desktop, but on mobile when i scroll down the video stops, when i scroll back up the video src changes to the one it had before

Comment: Sadly I do not have the devices to help you out on that.